# Any help appreciated. R: Creating function that calculates sqrt of x, if x is negative return Na

Tags: r

Create a function that, given a numeric value x, calculates the square root of x. If the value contained in x is negative it should return NA.

Comment: Check `?sqrt`...

Comment: `sqrt2<-function(x)suppressWarnings(ifelse(x<0,NA,sqrt(x)))`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be:

```
fun <- function(x) x^.5
fun(3)
# [1] 1.732051
fun(-1)
# [1] NaN
```

If `NA` needed instead of `NaN`, use an `ifelse`.

```
fun2 <- function(x) ifelse(x < 0, NA, x^.5)
fun2(-1)
# [1] NA
fun2(3)
# [1] 1.732051
fun2(c(-1, 3))
# [1]       NA 1.732051
```

Comment: Is `NaN` the same as `NA`?

Comment: @Edward Actually not, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5686/what-is-the-difference-between-nan-and-na. I've extended my answer to when `NA` is needed.

Comment: I know they're not the same.  I was indirectly directing you to the fact that the OP wanted NA, not NaN.   ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ifelse` to define your vectorized custom function `f`, e.g.,

```
f <- Vectorize(function(x) ifelse(x>=0,sqrt(x),NA))
```

or

```
f <- function(x) suppressWarnings(ifelse(x>=0,sqrt(x),NA))
```

**Example**

```
> f(c(-1,0,1,2,3))
[1]       NA 0.000000 1.000000 1.414214 1.732051
```